# Constructor in double inheritance

Tags: c++, object, constructor, default-constructor

I have a problem with my constructor. I have class vehicle, then I made class `motorVehicle` which inherited after `vehicle` and then I want to make class `motorcycle` which inherits after class `motorVehicle` and I can't make my default constructor because I have error:
Class `vehicle` and `motorVehicle` isn't changed by me and class `motorcycle` is in 2 option none of these option works but I give you both of them. Btw the problems are (First option): no matching constructor for initialization of 'motorVehicle' and with second option  expected ; after expression and expected member name or ;  after declaration specifiers

```
class vehicle {
public:
    int numberOfWheels;
    string color;
    float vehiclePayload;

    vehicle(): numberOfWheels{4},color{"black"},vehiclePayload{500}{

    }
};
class motorVehicle : public vehicle {
public:
    float tankCapacity;
        float fuelConsumption;
        float mileage;
        float currentAmountOfFuel;
        int yearOfProduction;
        unsigned long long int vin;
        motorVehicle(): tankCapacity{30}, fuelConsumption{6}, mileage{100}, currentAmountOfFuel{10}, yearOfProduction{2021}, vin{1}, vehicle{4, "black", 500} {

        }
};


class motorcycle : public motorVehicle{
public:
    float bootSize;
    string brand;
    string model;
    motorcycle(): bootSize{500}, brand{"Ninja"}, model{"Kawasaki"}, motorVehicle{30,6,100,10,2021,1,vehicle{4, "black", 500}}{

    }

};

class motorcycle : public motorVehicle{
public:
    float bootSize;
    string brand;
    string model;
    motorcycle(): bootSize{500}, brand{"Ninja"}, model{"Kawasaki"}, motorVehicle(){30,6,100,10,2021,1,vehicle{4, "black", 500}}{

    }

};
```

Comment: first you don't have any parameters in any of your constructors so the c++ compiler would not find a matching constructor. Then, if you inherit from a class (B), you can only use it's constructor and if there are params you want to pass on to it's parent (A) you should do it in the constructor : B(int foo): A(foo)

Comment: Your base classes only have default constructor, i.e., you can't directly construct the values via member constructors. You'd need to sent in the body of the constructor or you use the base class's implicitly created copy constructor. The alternative is to give them suitable constructors. As an aside: `public` member variables are generally an indication that the class isn't an abstraction. Of course, the same holds true for classes which have getter/setter member functions for all their member variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base classes do not declare any constructor taking actual values. As these classes *do* declare a default constructor, aggregate initialisation doesn't work: there is a declared constructor, i.e., the class isn't an aggregate. If you want to directly initialise the base class you *could* use their implicitly generate copy constructor, though. However, you'd still need to populate the content of the class separately as you'll need to created the  object using a default constructor:

```
class motorVehicle : public vehicle {
public:
    float tankCapacity;
    float fuelConsumption;
    float mileage;
    float currentAmountOfFuel;
    int yearOfProduction;
    unsigned long long int vin;
    motorVehicle(): tankCapacity{30}, fuelConsumption{6}, mileage{100}, currentAmountOfFuel{10}, yearOfProduction{2021}, vin{1},
        vehicle([]{
            vehicle rc;
            rc.numberOfWheels = 4;
            rc.color = "black";
            rc vehiclePayload = 500;
            return rc;
            }()) {

    }
 };
```

Obviously, instead of using a lambda function you could have a factor function, let's say `makeVehicle(int wheels, std::string const& color, float payload)` appropriately initialising the members. There should really be a suitable constructor for `vehicle`, though.

Comment: I think I understand but how my class motorcycle should look to work?

Comment: You just apply the same technique, constructing a `motorVehicle` and initialising it via its copy constructor instead of a `vehicle`.

Comment: Thank you very very much, you helps me a lot!

Comment: @Jakub: the currency at Stackoverflow is voting for responses and, assuming they answer the question, accepting the one which answers the question best.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find the button to accept the answer, but I've already done it! :)